# Is it possible to change the timezone of moment object?

Tags: reactjs, react-datetime

I am developing a reactjs application, I want to set timezone to my application.I am using react-datetime package for date and time selection.

My requirement is, My Application need to works with user's selected timezone.
For example, In my profile I set America/losangels timezone but I am in India. so the date pickers need to show/give America/losangels date and time but I am getting IST date and time.

Is it possible to change the react-datetime picker timzone?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [moment timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/) library.

You can then set the default timezone that `moment` will use ([docs](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/default-timezone/):

```
import moment from 'moment-timezone';
moment.tz.setDefault("America/New_York");
```

Now, when react-datetime creates/formats new moments, they should be in this timezone.